# Solving for $n$ when in exponents of differences

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have an equation where

$$ \frac{(c^n  + y)}{(a^n - b^n)} = \frac{C}{(a-b)} $$

In my case, $ y << c^n $ , so I could potentially simplify the equation to:

$$ \frac{c^n}{(a^n - b^n)} = \frac{C}{(a-b)} $$

or further

$$ \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^n - \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^n = \frac{(a-b)}{C} $$

I have everything except $n$.

Can I solve for $n$, given $a$, $b$, $c$ and $C$?

Can I solve for $n$, given $a$, $b$, $c$, $y$ and $C$ without having to resort to the approximation and taking away $y$?

Comment: Yes, numerically.

Comment: Any pointers to how I can do that? I can always solve for n by putting all this into excel sheet, one row for each value of n and see where it matches. But I was hoping to get a formula, where I feed in a,b,c and C and get n..

Comment: There's probably no explicit formula for $n$ in terms of $a,b,c,C$. As for numerical method with precision higher than “looking”, binary search is a good one.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Let's see if someone else has an interesting idea..